# What is the difference between void function and frutial function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Now I am watching PY4E youtube, the difference between void and fruitial function does not touch me well. just return value?

Also, if the void function has a function `PRINT(SOMETHING)`
even though it has not return value, but it has some value or result?
isn't it? I am little bit confused.

Comment: You mean a "fruitful function"? Seems like it's just the return/no-return...

Comment: In Python, a function with no return statement returns `None`. Functions may also fail to return at all by raising an exception or by looping infinitely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, all functions return something, but some return `None`, which is ignored. These are called "void". Functions that return anything else are called "fruitful".

For example, `list.append()`:

```
>>> a = []
>>> a.append(1)
```

Note how nothing was printed after `a.append()`. But it did actually return `None`, which we can confirm by printing its return value:

```
>>> print(a.append(2))
None
```

`print` as well returns none:

```
>>> print(print(a.append(3)))
None
None
```

And user-defined functions which don't have a `return` statement return `None`.

Comment: thanks for kind answer!  so void function actually has some value "none" right?

Comment: @NORU Yes, void functions return `None`. I edited to clarify.

Comment: Now I got it! your explaination was so cool!